# Doctrine query builder - any of joined elements

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following entities (simplified):
a work is composed of multiple tasks. Each task has a field storing the time it should be due and a field storing the time it has been completed.

```
/**
* Work
*
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Work
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="work", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_work_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $task;

    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->task = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}



/**
* Task
*
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Task
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Work", inversedBy="task")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="work_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $work;

    /**
    * @var \DateTime
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="completed", type="datetime", nullable=true)
    */
    private $completed;

    /**
    * @var \DateTime
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="duedate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
    */
    private $duedate;


}
```

I am trying to build a query to retrieve all works that have uncompleted overdue tasks.

I initially thought something like this:

```
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:Work');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v');
        $query->leftJoin('v.task', 't');
        $query->andWhere(
            $query->expr()->isNull('t.completed')
        )
        ->andWhere(
            $query->expr()->gte('t.duedate', ':now')
        )
        ;

        $query->setParameter('now', new \DateTime(), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
```

However, this retrieves works whose ***all*** tasks are overdue (I think).

So I tried with a sub-query:

```
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:Work');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v');

        $query2 = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder();

        $query2->select('t')
            ->from('v.task', 't');

        $query2->andWhere(
            $query->expr()->isNull('t.completed')
        )
        ->andWhere(
            $query->expr()->gte('t.duedate', ':now')
        )
        ;

        $query2->setParameter('now', new \DateTime(), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);

        $query->andWhere(
            $query->expr()->any(
                $query2->getDql()
            )
        );
```

But I get the following error:

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 104: Error: Expected known function, got 'ANY'
```

Any idea on how I could write the query?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a repository for $query2